# Query Related to Assets Folder

Tags: android, assets

consider i have 10 images in assets folder and i retrieve it to Image View.And i have added another 10 more images to assets folder.Will i be able to view all 20 images on image view?If not why?If so how?

This is the code that i used to read and copy assets file to SD card

```
String[] getImagesFromAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] img_files = null;
    try {
       // img_files = getAssets().list("pictures");
        img_files = assetManager.list("pictures");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameActivity.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return img_files;


}

void loadImage(String name) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

   InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      in = assetManager.open("pictures/" + name);
      File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+"pictures/"+ name);

      out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
      copyFile(in, out);
      in.close();
      in = null;
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      out = null;



      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outFile.getAbsolutePath());

      image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);



    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + "pictures/" + name, e);
        return;
    } 

}



private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int read;
      while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
      {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use 3rd party libs, Use Acceptable URIs examples in android [**Android-Universal-Image-Loader**](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Ex: `String imageUri = "assets://image.png";`

Credits: Sergey Tarasevich

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But my problem is i would like to store images in assets folder itself and i have saved no of images count using preference.what i find is when i add new images to assets folder i don't find the counter to increment.